# wrong installed eclipse

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, eclipse

I have got a rather stupid question:
While trying to install eclipse on Ubuntu 16 04 I just downloaded the tar gz archive, extracted it from archive manager and executed the eclipse-inst. 
Now I have a directory with seemingly working eclipse but the system does not recognize eclipse as an installed app.
What would be the best way to make the system reognize eclipse?

greetings.

Comment: what do you mean by recognize as installed app?

Comment: it does not appear in the set of installed programms (so I have to start it from the eclipse.exe )

Comment: You have to create a launcher for it so you see it in `dash`... Let me help with that

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse isn't installed via `apt` hence you won't see it in the `dash` like so many other application. You have to create a launcher for it, and this can be done thus:

1. Create a `.desktop` file in one of two places:

   - `gedit /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
   - `sudo -H gedit /usr/local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
2. Drop this code in that file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Eclipse
   Type=Application
   Exec=/home/USERNAME/java-mars/eclipse/eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/home/USERNAME/java-mars/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   NoDisplay=false
   Categories=Development;IDE;
   Name[en]=Eclipse
   ```

Note:

1. For launcher for you alone you install here: `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
2. For every one who uses that system you install launcher here:
   `/usr/local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
3. `USERNAME`: here refers to your username
4. And the name and location of your eclipse might be different from what I have given here, please change accordingly.
5. Restart the system.

With this you will now see `eclipse launcher icon` in `dash` and you don't need to always run it from its location as you are already doing.